# "Missing Values in 'X' Error" using nnet function in caret library in R

Tags: r, neural-network, r-caret, data-science

I am trying to fit a neural network to predict if a transaction should be flagged and I have a large sample from my data (50,000+ Rows by 211 variables with no blanks, NAs, etc due to preprocessing and only sampling complete data).  I am trying to fit both a NN on the data and another NN after running PCA. The variable I want to predict is in column 23 Here is my code:

```
apply(Train,2,function(x) sum(is.na(x)))
#returns 0 for all columns
NN=nnet(Train[,-23],Train[,23], softmax = TRUE)
# Error in nnet.default(x, y, ...) : missing values in 'x'
PCANN=pcaNNet(CBdata_Train2_IT[,-23],CBdata_Train2_IT[,23])
# Error in nnet.default(x, y, ...) : missing values in 'x'
```

I can't for the life of me figure out why and have been debugging and it seems related to the nnet.default function call...

Comment: Hard to answer without looking at your data. What's the output of `sum(is.na(Train))`?

Comment: Providing a reproducible example and the results of `sessionInfo` will help get your question answered.